# How to set SendClaimsIn for azure ad b2c REST call

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have  created an AAD B2C custom policy which makes a call  to call our REST API when a new user signs up by creating a custom Azure AD B2C custom policy.But i have to set two values to REST API.  Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key in header and email id in body.but i have to set SendClaimsIn only as either header or body.
so i added SendClaimsIn as header.But i cdont know how to set both values as inputclaim.My code is

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Signup REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-ValidateProfile">
      <DisplayName>Check loyaltyId Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://myapicall.io/api/</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Header</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestApiBearerToken" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type"  "DefaultValue"="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

its shows validation error while uploading

> makes a reference to ClaimType with id "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" but
>   neither the policy nor any of its base policies contain such an
>   element

i want to set header as Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key as "12345"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following inside of the `<ClaimsSchema>` tag near the top of the file:

```
<ClaimType Id="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key">
  <DisplayName>OCP APIM Subscription Key</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

Change the values inside of the `<InputClaims>` in your REST-ValidateProfile technical profile to the following:

```
<InputClaims>
  <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" DefaultValue="12345" />
</InputClaims>
```

You don't need a `grant_type` input claim for a static OAuth2 bearer (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api)).

Comment: you mean no need Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key for API management verification in azure for call this rest api via static token?